Weird bumps on my Carbon frame fork
I recently noticed some unusual bumps on the fork of my carbon bike. The paint is intact, and there are no visible cracks or signs of damage. However, the bumps seem to follow the pattern of the carbon fiber structure.
Has anyone experienced something similar? What could these bumps indicate? Are they a sign of internal damage or just a normal characteristic of the carbon material?


The bumps are clearly along the matrix. Not sure if normal or not but no damage, either completely normal or a manufacturing defect - probably a small one. Maybe not enough epoxy in a very small region?

I'd try contacting the manufacturer.
